# Wait for javascript to load page in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, web-scraping, html-parsing, webbrowser-control

I need to **scrape** some pages, the problem is that some of these pages are using javascript to load part of their contexts and some not! and there is no common tag or content to determine if context loaded! also I can't use timer or loop to wait and check if context changed! Currently I'm using web-browser to **scrape** and pars the context.

I'm already using following code to check if page completely loaded and check if page content is changed but it's not work properly.

```
while (wb.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
  {
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
  }
```

Any idea how tackle this? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following code will help you

Create a function method to wait for a few seconds

```
    public void Wait(int sec)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        if (sec == 0 || sec < 0) return;
        timer1.Interval = sec * 1000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Stop();

        };
        while (timer1.Enabled)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

Write the following code in the `DocumentCompleted` event. Check the element has value or null if null wait for 2 sec and continue this process 30 times, nearly one minute. If it is not loaded display a message like a page not loaded

```
int cnt = 0;
HtmlElement htmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementID")
do
{
    Wait(2);
    cnt++;
    htmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementID")
    if (cnt > 30)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
} while (htmlElement == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If scraping using a browser works, then try using [PuppeteerSharp](https://github.com/kblok/puppeteer-sharp), which is a "Headless Chrome .NET API".

You should be able to do the same thing entirely in C#.